# Ping monitoring for a comma separated file in Bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create a ping monitoring for OpenVPN client devices.

I want to ping all devices, from a IP list.

The `.txt` file is looking like this:

```
client1,10.8.0.2
client2,10.8.0.3
client3,10.8.0.3
.. and so on
```

I want the bash script to create a .txt file which contains the following:

```
client1: online
client2: offline
client3: online
and so on.
```

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Start with `while IFS=, read -r name ip; do
    ping "$ip";
done < infile > outfile`, google what `$?` means in a shell script, and get back to us if you have a problem later AFTER you've tried to figure out the rest for yourself.

Comment: thank you my friend!! i will have a look at it and come back to you if i have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

For my needs I use this script:

```
#! /bin/bash
while read -r client address
do
    ping -c 1 $address
    ret=$?
    if [[ 0 -eq $ret ]] 
    then
        echo "$client: online"
    else
        echo "$client: off line"
    fi
done < clients
```

With:

```
IFS=,
```

Set comma as field separator

```
while read -r foo bar
```

Read a file and store fields in `client` and `adrress` variables

```
pinc -c 1 address
```

Ping the `address` **only once**

```
ret=$?
```

Get `ping` command returned value (0 when all goes right)

if [[ 0 -eq $ret ]] ....

test if `ping` succedded

```
echo "$client: online"
```

Given `ping` result, print online or off line

```
done < clients
```

Idiomatic construction to read a file line by line

Comment: No need to explicitly reference `$?`.  It is cleaner to write: `if ping -c 1 "$address"; then status=online; else status=offline; fi; printf "%s: %s" "$client" "$status";`